# Low freq rumble with Sennheiser Mkh30

Tags: microphone

Hi all

I finally have a Sennheiser mkh-30 to pair with my mkh-60. I bought it used. While checking it, I noticed how the 30 is sensitive to movements and vibrations, even in my Rycote kit: lots of low freq rumble.

Tomorrow I'll listen to the recording tests in studio, but is it normal? I see in the specs that it goes down to 40 hz, but it really pick up lots of rumble with every slightly movement.

If it is ok, do you record with your HPF turned on or apply the eq later, in the studio while decoding the MS recording?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the dumb question

Davide

Comment: Just fired up my mkh30/60 and have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a connbox, I'd suggest getting one...or at least using some gaff. tape to fix the mic cable in place. It's been my experience that loose cables are usually the culprit when you get rumble in suspension situations. If you find another solution though, do share.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I already ordered a connbox with the stereo rycote kit: it should help a lot, I think. 

I'm worried that maybe the microphone is defective... but the sound is really good, to my ears... just lots of low freq rumble.

Comment: @Davide - it's always possible. if you find it happening even when it's not being handled, you may want to send it in to sennheiser to have it serviced. i have no experience with the mkh30, but if @noisejockey sees this thread, perhaps he'll weigh in.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a Senny MKH MS pair in a Rycote windscreen, with a connbox (dual 3-pin to 5-pin XLR, natch). I've never had an issue with LF rumble from the MKH30 that I can recall, at least with regards to handling noise. I know I always keep the HPF's off on the mics, but I do sometimes use a HPF on the recorder for nature sounds. I think you're on the right track: Get the connbox into your setup and see if it helps. If not, you might consider servicing, but I'd be very surprised if you needed to return the mic due to loose construction or fittings.

Comment: I agree it is highly unlikely that the mic has loose fittings, the connbox should be added to your setup first.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Maybe it's really only a problem with the cable. I ordered the connbox3 with the stereo rycote kit, I'm sure it gonna help. Anyway, next week I'll rent another mkh30 and do a quick comparison.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have some good suggestions for troubleshooting but High Pass Filters are really necessary when you are "cueing" when using a Rycote. Whether it is on a boom or handheld with a pistol grip, you are going to need a high pass.  As Nathan mentioned, the connbox is a step in the right direction. Personally, I feel like the connbox should just be a standard part of the product. If you look at the Rycote product design, you have mics that are suspended by bands and they are designed to move a bit, so that is where he high-pass comes in. The newer lyres don't function this way, but having a 60 Hz roll off is never a bad idea.  The MKHs also have an exaggerated low end, so I can't image having a gentle 60 hz high pass is going to be a real issue for your recording, but it will definitely deal with a lot of "vibration"

Comment: @sepulchra. Thanks for chiming in. Do you have a good HPF to look for? The one on my recorder and on the mkh30 are too high, for my taste. Do you have the Schoeps HPF?

Comment: @what recorder are you using?  If you are looking for a barrell filter in-line schoeps LC-60s are great.

Comment: @sepulchra I use mainly my Tascam HD-P2: I'll look for the Schoeps

Answer (score 2):

I received my coonbox: that little thing really change the game! Less handling noise with the mkh30, and with every other microphone I tried. I used to have a short cable from the blimp to the handle of the Rycote (and then another one, long connected to the recorder), but the Connbox is really much better.

I still have a bit of low rumble noise with the 30, hope to rent another one this week and do some tests.

Thanks all you guys

Comment: We all appreciate the report back, Davide. Continue to update us as things go forward. Glad you have at least a partial solution!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest hiring an identical mic and checking if the rumble is still present.  If the mic was second hand you might find that the capsule is moving very slightly in the mounting.

Comment: That's my plan. Next week I'm going to rent another mkh30 and see if my mic need servicing. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How were you recording? I've only encountered rumbling when recording some foley, I ended up wrapping the legs of the mic stand in foam and this solved my problem.

Also depending on the room, you can sometimes pick up what sounds like rumble, but its just the tone of the room.

Comment: I was just checking the mic, at home; mic inside the mono rycote kit. The rumble was definitely related with the microphone movements. Maybe it's only noise cable, but I'm worried that the capsule is a little loose.. 

Answer (score 1):

Figure of eight microphones such as the MKH-30 are by their design quite a lot more sensitive to movement than other microphone types. I don't remember the exact reason, but it has got something to do with the way it is equally sensitive on both sides of the membrane, making it more sensitive to impacts, wind and very low frequencies. So you need to keep a steady hand when moving it around, especially when recording quieter sounds.

I have used (rented) a lot of different Sennheiser MS microphone setups (MKH-40/30 or MKH 50/30) over the years, and I have often experienced more rumble related to movement on the MKH-30 compared to the other microphone.

So it may not be a faulty microphone, but I think it is a good idea to compare your MKH-30 with another MKH-30 anyway.

With the right rycote and cables you should be able to get a useable recording, even if you and the rest of the crew are running.

Comment: thanks Morten. I'll run a test and compare the 30s. 
With the same setup I get a lot more rumble from the mkh30 then from the mkh60 (or from the schoeps mk4, that I know better). Maybe it's just the design and the cable movement... I hope so :)

Comment: Again, you can't really compare an MKH60 (shotgun) or an MK4 (cardiod) to an MKH30 (figure of eight), because of the physical difference in design. You might want to compare the MKH30 with the Schoeps MK8, which is also figure of eight. Actually a Schoeps MK4/MK8 setup is my favourite for MS, it sounds really rich and full compared to the Sennheiser setup.